# Installation of biopython - python 3.3 not found in registry

Tags: python, windows-7, registry, biopython

I am trying to install biopython to run with Python 3.3 on a Windows7 computer.

I have downloaded the biopython executable biopython-1.61.win32-py3.3-beta.exe. When I attempt to run the executable, however, I get the message "Python version 3.3 is required, which is not found in the registry." Python version 3.3 is present on my computer. I have been running programs through it for a month or two. It was installed from the file python-3.3.0.amd64.msi, and is located in the Program Files (x86) directory.I have tried reinstalling Python 3.3 but get the same error message.

Does anyone know how to get around this problem?

Comment: Did you install a different version of Python after 3.3?  That might have changed the registry settings.  Alternatively on cmd.exe, `ASSOC .py=Python.File`
`FTYPE Python.File="C:\Python33\python.exe" "%%1" %%*` (or whatever your path is).

Comment: Just thought of something else.  You have the 64-bit version of Python, do you have a 64-bit biopython?

Answer (score 11):

Python.org provides Windows installers in two flavours, 32 bit ("win32") and 64 bit ("amd64"). You need matching library installers for your Python version. You are trying to use a 32 bit Biopython installer with a 64 bit Python.

As instructed here http://biopython.org/wiki/Download there are experimental 64 bit Windows installers for Biopython, NumPy, etc here: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Or, you can install the 32-bit version of Python 3.3 for Windows, and then use biopython-1.61.win32-py3.3-beta.exe

Comment: You can mark an answer as accepted (that's what all these silly scores and badges are partly about).

Answer (score 0):

You can try to solve this problem by fixing a blank option in the Windows registry. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11507968/3962648 provide details of similar issue when installing numpy.
In short, you can just run the windows command line and type in: "reg copy HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Python HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Python /s"

Answer (score -1):

probelm is windows 64bit and biopython 32bit...
to get the 64bit version of biopython get this one:
http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Comment: This is identical to [an existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15163523/570918) posted months earlier.