# Python 3.3. not found in registry

Tags: python, windows, registry

I have python 3.3 installed on my windows system.  When I do

```
python -v
```

I get 3.3

However when I try to install `Pillow-2.1.0.win32-py3.3.‌exe` from `http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/`

I get:

```
Python version 3.3. required, which was not found in the registry
```

any tips?

Comment: It looks like your Python interpreter targets the x64 platform (and stores information in the 64-bits part of the registry), whereas the Pillow module targets the x86 (Win32) platform.

Comment: There is no need to download Pillow from Gohlke's page. It is listed on PyPI too, with a 64bit version available. See https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/2.1.0#downloads

Comment: This post seems very similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15161315/installation-of-biopython-python-3-3-not-found-in-registry?rq=1.

Hope that helps.