# Installation of pygame with Anaconda

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame, anaconda

I have `Anaconda 1.6.2`, which uses `Python 2.7.5`, installed on a `Windows 7 64-bit` system. 
I need to install `Pygame 1.9.1` and this is not part of the `conda repository`.  
I cannot run the `Windows installer` because `Anaconda` has not made registry entries for `Python` and the `.msi` does not recognize the Python version. 
So, I tried to install `Pygame` from source. What I originally wanted to do was create a conda package as per the instructions here http://www.continuum.io/blog/conda As per those instructions, the package (pygame in this case) is first installed from source and then a conda package is created. But, I failed in the pygame install. 
On running the `setup.py` file `("python setup.py install")`, a run time error 
 
`"mingw32: required environment variable MINGW_ROOT_DIRECTORY not set"` is thrown. 
 After setting the environment variables, I ran the setup again and this time, the runtime error became "The dependencies are linked to the wrong C runtime for Python 2.7".

Error:

```
WARNING, DLL for smpeg library not found.
WARNING, DLL for tiff library not found.
WARNING, DLL for SDL_ttf library not found.
WARNING, DLL for SDL_image library not found.
WARNING, DLL for vorbisfile library not found.
WARNING, DLL for jpeg library not found.
WARNING, DLL for vorbis library not found.
WARNING, DLL for SDL_mixer library not found.
WARNING, DLL for png library not found.
WARNING, DLL for SDL library not found.
WARNING, DLL for ogg library not found.
WARNING, DLL for z library not found.
WARNING, DLL for portmidi library not found.
running install
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 491, in <module>
    setup(**PACKAGEDATA)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\distutils\core.py", line 152, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 563, in run
    self.run_command('build')
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 127, in run
    self.run_command(cmd_name)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "setup.py", line 352, in run
    sys.version_info[:2])
RuntimeError: The dependencies are linked to the wrong C runtime for Python 2.7
```

The `distutils.cfg` file in \Anaconda\Lib\distutils reads

```
[build]
compiler = mingw32
```

Please tell me what I need to do to install `Pygame with Anaconda`. I'm not able to find any information (barely any) regarding this combination. I would just like to add that Pygame was originally working when I had a Python 2.7.5 installation. The problem has come up now when I uninstalled my original Python installation and moved to Anaconda.

Thank you!

Comment: If you don't want to search for the latest answer below, and avoid solutions which worked in the past but not now, just go to the [search results](https://anaconda.org/search?q=pygame)    at anaconda site. Most used repository is [this one](https://anaconda.org/cogsci/pygame) today). Also avoid mixing conda and pip install when not absolutely necessary, as this can break packages compatibility.

Answer (score 41):

The easiest way to install Python using conda is:

`conda install -c https://conda.binstar.org/krisvanneste pygame`

### Edit (03/2016):

It seems like the package is unavailable, but you can use this instead:

`conda install -c https://conda.anaconda.org/tlatorre python`

### Edit (01/2017)

The command has changed, now you can use:

`conda install -c tlatorre pygame=1.9.2`

### Edit (07/2018)

tlatorre's repo is still valid but a little bit outdated, you can use cogsci repo if you want the latest version:

`conda install -c cogsci pygame`

Comment: Yes, finally a way that simply works! Only thing is that I had to run CMD "as administrator" to be allowed to run this command.

Comment: Thanks for this, huge help :)

Comment: Actually It seems to be unable, but you can use this:
conda install -c https://conda.anaconda.org/tlatorre <package>

Comment: In your edit, the last word, you meant pygame? (it is written python)

Comment: I tried it on my 32bit windows but it complained "Package not found package missing in current win-32 channels -pygame 1.9.2*"

Comment: Not for Windows. 
For windows: conda install -c https://conda.anaconda.org/prkrekel pygame

Comment: I prefer the method of Gerry Laureys as you don't have to worry about pygame version or your system terminal. It just works.

Answer (score 19):

In the Anaconda menu, choose Tools, then "open command prompt".

The cmd window will open inside Anaconda. Now type "pip install pygame".

Comment: I accomplished it this way via Spyder, pretty much the same way.

Comment: did not work for me at first. It threw an error. I run it again and it installed. Wonder why

Comment: On windows this  is great.

Comment: As of 2019, there seems to be issues with `conda install`. Using `pip` works perfectly.

Answer (score 16):

This worked for me:

1. Open Anaconda Prompt (from Start Menu > Anaconda3)
2. Type command '***pip install pygame***'
3. Open Spyder and import pygame

It should work.

Comment: This should get more upvotes. Some packages you don't want to mess around with conda installers they just aren't very well maintained. This is one of those cases. Just use pip!

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me on windows :

```
conda install -c cogsci pygame=1.9.2a0
```

This didnot work for me on windows machine :

```
conda install -c tlatorre pygame=1.9.2
```

Comment: This saved my sanity.  Various other channels have been recommended here, but `cogsci` was the only one I found that could supply a 64-bit pygame package.

Comment: I tried this but then could not install the spyder to use with it.

Answer (score 3):

Trying to **update this answer for 2023**. Use conda forge:

```
conda install -c conda-forge pygame
```

Requirements (source: https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/pygame):

> - pygame -> python[version='3.10.*|3.9.*|3.11.*|3.8.*']
> - pygame -> python[version='>=3.10,<3.11.0a0|>=3.8,<3.9.0a0|>=3.9,<3.10.0a0|>=3.11,<3.12.0a0']

For older versions of python, keep using cogsci (source https://anaconda.org/cogsci/pygame):

```
conda install -c cogsci pygame
```

pip may also be an option. Activate your conda environment and type:

```
pip install pygame
```

Answer (score 1):

The following works with Anaconda2 on Win7 (32bit).

```
conda install -c cogsci pygame=1.9.2
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do the job, as i see, is to reinstall Anaconda using its Windows installer so that later you can install your pygame using Windows installer too. This could save your much work in installer pygame from source.

Note that the versions of your Anaconda and pygame should be both 32 or 64 bits, and be using the same python version.

Comment: Well, that's what I originally tried. And, like I said, that did not work because the Windows Installer for Pygame is not able to find and installed version of Python, something to do with the registry entries made by Anaconda

Comment: So your Anaconda did not make registry entries of its Python into Windows 7 64 bits, as I understand. But in my case my Anaconda does with a Python 64 installation on my Windows 8 64 bits. This is not strange with python under Windows, though. If you need write entries of python mannually, you may go to http://stackoverflow.com/a/11507968/2850534.

Comment: Are you using the official pygame, or the unofficial from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame?

Comment: The official version. And, yes, the Anaconda installation does not seem to have made registry entries. But, I shall try the solution you provided of writing registry entries manually.

Answer (score 0):

With anaconda python 3 on MacOs 10.12 I followed the following procedure and it worked : http://florian-berger.de/en/articles/installing-pygame-for-python-3-on-os-x/

I only skipped the following line since pip was already installed through anaconda:

```
/usr/local/share/python3/easy_install pip
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Jupyter Notebook 5.5.0 and running "install pygame" without the pip command allowed for the installation of pygame 1.9.3 for Python 3.6.5 on windows

Answer (score -2):

For anyone with a Linux computer I found a link that might be helpful:

https://anaconda.org/tlatorre/pygame

run this command in your terminal :

```
conda install -c tlatorre pygame=1.9.2
```

Then close Spyder and restart it