# how to install pygame package in jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, installation, pygame, package, anaconda

I've installed the pygame package in python and it is working fine but i am not able to install that same package in conda. Does anaconda have the pygame package.If not than what else can i use instead of pygame?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installation of pygame with Anaconda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19636480/installation-of-pygame-with-anaconda)

Answer (score 2):

Typing "conda pygame" into your favorite internet search engine would have answered your question immediately. Yes, there is someone who packages pygame for conda, you just have to specify the correct channel.

Also, this question has been asked before, and the answer has been updated repeatedly: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32699498/11451509

The latest and currently applicable command is

```
conda install -c cogsci pygame
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem to install pygame in my jupyter notebook with Python 3.7. Spent couple of hours reading the stack overflow + tried and testing all the codes. Still didn't work.
Lastly, I found this useful video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4NH6UitQrtk , which saved my day. Just need to type "pip install pygame" in the Anacoda prompt. It works!!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZzqUL.png)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32624670)